# How can I send a Booster plugin templated email using php?

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, hook

I have a custom email template (made with Booster plugin) which I want to send to customer by conditional logic. Here's a function:

```
function tt_foreign_bank_notice_email ( $order_id ) { 
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $order_data = $order->get_data();
    $payment_method = $order->get_payment_method();
    $order_billing_country = $order_data['billing']['country'];

    if ( $order_billing_country != 'LV' && $payment_method == 'bacs' ) {

        // NEED TO SEND EMAIL TEMPLATE wc_email_wcj_custom_8 TO CUSTOMER

    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'tt_foreign_bank_notice_email' );
```

How do I call to send this email in my function?

Comment: go in WooCommerce -> Settings -> E-mails -> New order and you will see all informations to customise this e-mail.

Comment: @Kaperto I don't need to customize this email, I need to send another email by conditional logic.

Comment: You'll have better luck asking the developers of that plugin. I looked for any documentation they had, but nothing covered what you're looking for.

Comment: @KGreene I believe it'd be much faster to simply add a note for customer